# iOS UICalloutBar crash

Tags: ios, debugging, crash

I am getting the following crash report for my app.  Any ideas as to how I would go about debugging something like this?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x417d37f6

Thread 0: Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39048b26 objc_msgSend + 5
1  UIKit                          0x310643ed +[UICalloutBar fadeSharedCalloutBarIfNeededForTouchInView:window:] + 80
2  UIKit                          0x31064365 -[UITouchesEvent _dismissSharedCalloutBarIfNeeded] + 228
3  UIKit                          0x3102cf87 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 7070
4  CoreFoundation                 0x2e882183 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
5  CoreFoundation                 0x2e881653 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 206
6  CoreFoundation                 0x2e87fe47 __CFRunLoopRun + 622
7  CoreFoundation                 0x2e7eac27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
8  CoreFoundation                 0x2e7eaa0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
9  GraphicsServices               0x334de283 GSEventRunModal + 138
10 UIKit                          0x3108e049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
11 App                            0x000d441f main (main.m:6)
```

I don't use a UICalloutBar anywhere in my code.  It seems to be happening across a range of devices, but only in iOS7 and always while the app is focused.

I've seen this, but it didn't really help: [What is UICalloutBarButton, and why does it make my app crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5709489/105460)

Comment: Have you enabled your zombie in project?

Comment: these are crash reports coming from my production app, in which it is not enabled.  I can enable them in my dev environment, but I haven't seen this crash myself.

Comment: Is this working good in iOS6. Have you added the targets/selectors to all the call out buttons? And are you sure that the selectors are also available?

Comment: I don't use a UICalloutBar anywhere in my code.  Guess I should have mentioned that.  Updating the question.

Comment: Are you using ARC? seems that there's an object that is not being released or retain properly. I will check the zombie objects in order to detect where the issue is happening.

Comment: Could indicate that user's device is jailbroken and something else is causing the crash. Try to get more information about device.

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5709538/2754727

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I am basing this advice on the fact you have touch related crash also related to the dismissal of user interface, and that your customers are on production builds so there is no chance to specially instrument the system to dig into the problem.

I suggest using your app and make a note of all places a touch event results in a dialog, menu or popover being dismissed.  Then work out what other touch events could produce the same effect, and what touch events are listened to but not logically what you would expect the user to do.

For example, for a popover, you normally touch a menu item of the popover and it dismisses.  But what about pressing the popover title again (to toggle it off), or press outside the popover (which means dismiss the popover)?

Another example is where the user is expected to make a choice in a menu, but there is a back button they can press to roll back up.  You might not be using the system in this way  but users might press in such places.

Lastly, if you do user interface automation, you can try Monkey Testing.  That is, write a script (or download one of the open source implementations), which randomly taps on the screen.  Let it run on your app and see what it shakes out -- usually it finds touch problems in even robust apps.