# Crash when tapping on UITextField or UITextView: Assertion failure in -[UICalloutBarButton layoutSublayersOfLayer:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uikit, uitextview

Answers to similar questions did not help so I'm opening a new question.

I have this issue in several of my projects now:

Tapping on the first responder `UITextField` or on a `UITextView` (that would normally bring up the default context menu for copy and paste) causes my app(s) to crash.

**Note:** `UICalloutBarButton` is a `UIKit` private API, so there is no chance to change its `layoutSubviews` implementation and call `[super layoutSubviews]` in it.

**Log message:**

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICalloutBarButton layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8794
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. UICalloutBarButton's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.'
```

I don't have any idea why this appears. Would be very happy for any help.

---

**EDIT**

Trying to reproduce the crash in a demo project I found out that it is a custom `UIView` category that causes the crash. See accepted answer for more details.

---

Comment: It's fairly certain that you've misconfigured something.  You need to give a few clues as to how you've configured stuff, especially stuff that would be involved with text selection.  And maybe check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20197677/581994) for clues.

Comment: @Hot Licks Thanks for your comment. Will give an example tomorrow where this happens.

Comment: Can you share part of code and/or storyboard where it is happens. Or some demo project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By trying to reproduce the crash in a demo project I found out that it is a custom UIView category that causes the crash.

When creating this fault, I assumed that category methods were only available for `UIView` subclasses that `#import` this category.

But this is not the case as described in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html):

> ***Any*** methods that you declare in **a** category will be available to **all** instances of the original class, as well as **any** subclasses of the original class. At runtime, there’s no difference between a method added by a category and one that is implemented by the original class.

So not being aware of this, I had overridden in my custom category the `UIView` method `+ (BOOL) requiresConstraintBasedLayout` to return `YES` (like I wrongly thought only for those classes that import this category).

Putting a breakpoint in that method, I learned that this '*category-method*' gets called from **everywhere** in the UIKit once the category files are added to a project.

Nothing but a painful way of learning/accepting, that overriding methods in categories is **never** a good idea - unless you want to cause strange crashes like this ;-).

Sorry for stealing your time, but thank you for asking some code examples which forced me to seriously reproduce the problem - which lead me to the crash-cause...